# NTLM Proxy Authentication with Axis 1.4 client

Tags: java, soap, proxy, axis, ntlm

I need to add following functionality to a legacy Java client that uses **Axis 1.4** to access web services:

The client should route all http requests (Axis web service requests) through a **proxy** that accepts **NTLM authentication**.

I have configured the proxy as follows:

```java
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", configuration.getUsername());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", configuration.getPassword());
System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", configuration.getUsername());
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", configuration.getPassword());
```

This is working fine for **basic authentication**, but fails on my proxy with NTLM authentication.

**Is is possible to configure Axis 1.4 to authenticate with NTLM?** And if so, how would I go about this? After hours of research, I feel clueless as to how to approach this.

I have tried to set a custom Authenticator like this, but sadly to no effect.

```java
Authenticator.setDefault(
  new NtlmAuthenticator(configuration.getUsername(), configuration.getPassword())
);
```

Where NtlmAuthenticator looks like this:

```java
class NtlmAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private final String username;
    private final char[] password;

    public NtlmAuthenticator(final String username, final String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password.toCharArray();
    }

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(username, password));
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help that points me in the right direction!

Comment: Which Java version are you running ? Can you add `-Dntlm.debug` system property to your server startup and edit your post with the trace ?